# Find number of levels in a tree using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My rows have related row and those rows can have related rows. This tree can go down many levels (unknown). How can I find the number of levels my tree is according to one parameter?

For example:

```
select * from category a 
inner join category b on a.row=b.relatedRow 
inner join category c on b.row=c.relatedRow where a.row=?
```

So if there are items in `a`, level 1. If there are items in `b`, level 2 and so on. This way I can find that if row=1, there are 3 levels of other items that are related.

Comment: use a flat tree for example a closure table: `| ancestorRow | descendantRow | depth | `. query: `select max(depth) from category where ancestorRow = ?`

Answer (score 0):

create two php functions one is for getting main category and another one is for getting subcategories of main category.

```
function GetCategory($Cat_Id, $Cat_Name="")
{
$level = "";
echo $sql = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE 1=1 AND Cat_ParentId='0'";
$result = @mysql_query($sql);
while($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if(!empty($Cat_Id))
    {
        if($row['Cat_Id']==$Cat_Id)
        {
            $selected = "selected='selected'";
        }
        else
        {
            $selected = "";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $selected="";
    }

    $resul .=  $level.$row['Cat_Name']."<br />";
    $resul .= GetSubCateogry($row['Cat_Id'], $level);
}
return $resul;
}
function GetSubCateogry($Cat_Id, $level)
{
$level .= "--";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE Cat_ParentId = '$Cat_Id'";
$result = @mysql_query($sql);
while($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if(!empty($Cat_Id))
    {
        if($row['Cat_Id']==$Cat_Id)
        {
            $selected = "selected='selected'";
        }
        else
        {
            $selected = "";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $selected="";
    }

    $resul .=  $level.$row['Cat_Name']."<br />";
    $resul .= GetSubCateogry($row['Cat_Id'], $level);
}
return $resul;
}
echo GetCategory(1);
```

Comment: you can add count in query for perticular subcategory count